# Bootstrap Affix plugin navbar top delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest release of bootstrap 3. I am using the affix plugin to make a static navbar fixed. It works however, there is a significantly long delay before the navbar updates and becomes fixed to the top. It is repeatable on all browsers.

I figured it would be easiest to show the problem with a video, I also provided some code.

[see video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxfG2U55qf7XbUNEbWZPOF8tWTg/view?usp=sharing)

[see JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23010/)

```
<h1></h1>
```

The effect I want is a clean instant transition like

this "http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_affix&"

I should also point out that I am using jQuery to define my section heights and the affix offset, I initially thought this would be causing the delay however, now I think that is out of the question.

This feels like a performance issue to me. I think jQuery is taking a little bit too long to figure out the height and apply the styling to the navbar.

I am hoping someone might have some insight into this matter.

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: ok will do, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what the issue was.

I wrote used jQuery to get the height of the header (the content above the navbar) in this case it was a video, and made it the affix offset. The way I fixed my jumping issue is just make the offset property a function that calculated the height of the header instead of a static variable.

```
Here is the updated JSFiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23013/